# Displaying Entries by Category name not working

Tags: categories, segments, low-seg2cat

I'm using Low Seg2Cat and I'm trying to display a list of entries by their Category Name.

if I use the category id I can pull the entries, however using the Category name is a no go.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" dynamic="off" category="    
{segment_3_category_name}" status="open"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

this is the URL I'm using.

```
www.site.com/index.php/group/template_name/category_name
```

I've the latest version of seg2cat and set the extension to "search all sites."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yea, i just figured this out. And yes, you're right, it it does also work with the entries tag. One thing to remember, in the seg2cat settings if you have the same category name in 2 groups, select just the group you are querying. don't search everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lows Seg2cat you can use `{segment_3_category_id}`

EE can only use an id parameter in the channel entries tag.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" dynamic="off" category="{segment_3_category_id}" status="open"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is this cool? Don't really 'get' your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Low Seg2Cat is the "Magic" that needs to be in every EE install. It really should be "out-of-box."